# How to configure vscode to C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, configuration

I'm trying to compile a simple C++ project using vscode.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm encountering while trying to build the project is:
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[image: error message]

Which is weird because I can't find why the build is trying to use the program files path.

My tasks.json looks like:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I also changed the c_cpp_properties.json file to the above compiler path (which previously was the path to the visual studio dev tools compiler)

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/mingw-w64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Any ideas what else can I try, or what other configuration file I'm missing?

Thanks!

What I tried so far:

- By @brc-dd suggestion I tried to open code through terminal using
  `code -n .` and then opened the terminal in vscode to see the message

  \NVIDIA was unexpected at this time.
   So again, I went over
  the PATH variable and tried to enclose the path to nvidia stuff with
  " " (didn't know if it would help but also tried to add \ before the N, like \\Nvidia), closed the vscode and the terminal, reopened it all and still
  the same message appears.
- I also tried to compile through the terminal and it does work fine:

  C:\Users\x\Desktop\openGL>g++ -g hello_world.cpp -o hello_world.exe

  C:\Users\x\Desktop\openGL>

Edit:

user Path variable:

C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;
 C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
 C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm;
 C:\Program Files\CMake\bin

system PATH variable:

C:\mingw-w64\mingw32\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\;
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common";
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR;
C:\Users\x\Anaconda3\Scripts;
C:\Users\x\Anaconda3;
C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\windows\system32;
C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR";
C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Comment: It looks like a path was specified incorrectly as "Program Files" requires escaping.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: @tadman Yea, I looked it up before posting and tried to follow the env variables and added " " around the paths with white spaces but it didn't help. My problem is I can't find where this path specified and why the build uses it. It feels that maybe I'm missing some configuration somewhere.

Comment: You're going to have to find out either what the rest of that path is, which is hard because it gets cut at the first space, or find a setting that refers to something like that inadvertently.

Comment: can you confirm that you've opened vs-code on `c:\Users\xxx\Desktop\openGL`? Try running `cd C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\openGL` followed by `code -n .` from terminal. Then try running the build task. Also can you verify if you're able to compile your code by running the task from command line?

Comment: @brc-dd Thanks for the reply, I tried what you said, added more info to the post,

Comment: @MarkElishaev share your path variable in the post. Try changing the `command` parameter to "g++" in `tasks.json`.

Comment: @brc-dd added the Path variables. Also tried to change the command param to g++ and got the same output error

Comment: @MarkElishaev adding `"`'s in `PATH` is not exactly required. I think the problem is with `vs-code` configuration. Can you try running your code using `formulahendry.code-runner` extension on `vs-code`. Try following [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) step by step on a new directory and see if the problem persists. I will also recommend to first try reinstalling mingw-w64 on default location so that you'll get `compilerPath` like this `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-7.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe`. (Your version can defer from mine).

Comment: @brc-dd Thanks for your help, I finally managed to fix it. I reinstalled the mingw64 but I think the problem  occurred due to that after each change of the PATH variable i had to reload the whole VScode and not just the terminal inside (which i didn't know). I noticed by "echo %path%" that closing and reopening the the terminal in vscode isn't enough, the changes in PATH doesn't register.